# Is Java browser dependent?

Tags: browser, java

It seems that if you download Java from Java.com (not SDK or anything, just the regular java runtime), it gives you different versions depending on the browser you used.

So if I use 3 browsers (IE,FF,Ch), should I install JAVA through each and every one of them on a fresh windows installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed Java via Chrome on a clean Windows 7 installation that includes IE and FF.
I noticed that it also installed a FF add-on and an IE add-on, so you don't need to install Java separately from each browser, even if the installation file is slightly different.

Comment: There is one exception.  If you want to use the 64 bit version of IE or another browser, then you will need to install the 64 bit version of Java in addition to the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 1):

Should after installing or updating your Java Runtime you find that some applets are not running in one or more of your browsers you may have to enable them using your browser.
Each browser is different.
[First go to this java site](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml)
 jonathan is correct-answwering at the same time
 zoredache:- is also correct
 [For 64bit](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml)
hope things  work out